# Minimize a particular function in one variable

Tags: calculus, reference-request, optimization, asymptotics

For given $a,b$, what is the minimum value of the following expression?

$$
\frac{a}{x^2+b}+x,\qquad x>=0, a>0,b>0
$$

1. Differentiating the above gives a messy polynomial.
2. I tried plugging this into [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%5Ba%20%2F(b%2Bx%5E4)%20%2B%20x%5E2,%20x%5D) - It gives back the above polynomial.

I am looking for a reasonable **scaling** of the lower bound for the expression for $a,b \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: What is wrong with differentiating?

Comment: qbert: I am looking for a closed form solution. Differentiating the above expression results in an 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: and the parameter $a$ can also be negative you must do case work

Comment: Sonnhard: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Just use the quartic formula if you need to! All quartics can be solved exactly using elementary operations

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating, we get
$$\frac{-2 x (2 a x^2-(b+x^4)^2)}{(b+x^4)^2}$$
Setting the derivative to be zero, we get the following
$$-2 x (2 a x^2-(b+x^4)^2) = 0$$
Assuming $x$ can't be zero (make sure to check to see if $x=0$ is a minimum when finished) we get that
$$2 a x^2 = (b+x^4)^2$$
Can you solve from here? You can use the quartic formula to get the answer exactly (let $u=x^2$ first)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible approach.

$$
\frac{a}{x^2+b} + x \\
= \frac{a}{x^2+b} + x +\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{b} \\
> \frac{a}{x^2+b} + \sqrt{x^2+b} - \sqrt{b}\\
>a^{1/3} - \sqrt{b}
$$

Can we improve the lower-bound?